# What is the best sampling strategy for correlation analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, correlation, dimensionality-reduction

I have a big dataset, and i want to finds subspaces with high correlation among features. I want to take only samples of data. So, what is the best sampling strategy in this context.
Thanks